# What does Dickens' phrase "told forth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, charles-dickens

Charles Dickens *Little Dorrit* Chapter 25

> When he had thus disposed of his cards, all being done very quietly and in a suppressed tone, Mr Pancks puffed his way into his own breast-pocket and tugged out a canvas bag; from which, with a sparing hand, he **told forth** money for travelling expenses in two little portions.

What does "told forth money" mean in the above passage?

Comment: It's intriguing that [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell) doesn't have the meaning of *tell* that's being employed here. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell) does, though.

Answer (score 28):

Merriam-Webster has:

> **tell**
>
> 6 : COUNT, ENUMERATE
>
> > tell the stars, if thou be able to number them
> > Genesis 15:5 (King James Version)

It's why bank tellers are called tellers: they count money.

In your quoted passage, Mr Pancks **counted out** money (see MW [*count out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/count%20out) sense 3)

Comment: Interesting, an alternative to "tally".

Answer (score 18):

**Told forth** means "counted out", typically done in public (counting out money for a payment as you might do in front of a shopkeeper, rather than counting your money secretly).

It appears an old-fashioned usage, both this meaning of "tell" and of the specific expression "told forth".

*Tell* can mean "count", as in the King James Version where God tells Abraham he will have lots of decendants: "And he [God] brought him [Abraham] forth abroad, and said, Look now toward heaven, and tell the stars, if thou be able to number them: and he said unto him, So shall thy seed be." (Genesis 15:5) This example is given in [Merriam-Webster's entry for tell](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell), with the sense "count, enumerate".

In "told forth", *forth* is used with its [standard meanings in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forth), here "out into notice or view".

The Jacobean poet Ben Jonson wrote "Here's one outlived his peers / And told forth fourscore years" in [To the Immortal Memory and Friendship of That Noble Pair, Sir Lucius Cary and Sir Henry Morison](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50677/to-the-immortal-memory-and-friendship-of-that-noble-pair-sir-lucius-cary-and-sir-henry-morison). Here it is a metaphorical sense of counting out years, meaning living to a certain age.

Comment: cf. the idiom "all told"

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, my first thought was that it could also mean something similar to a Latin expression "relata refero" (I tell what I heard/was told). I guess I'm wrong.